# Why does a hashmap clear() free more memory than a pointer reassignment

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have an old and new map that contain hundred thousand entries:

```
Map<State, CostAndIndex> oldMap = new LinkedHashMap<State, CostAndIndex>();
Map<State, CostAndIndex> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<State, CostAndIndex>();
```

At the end of each iteration of a loop, I was simply doing this:

```
oldMap = newMap;
```

With that approach I was running out of memory after a while, even when calling System.gc(); after the reassignment.

Then I added a clear before the reassignment and I no longer run out of memory.

```
oldMap.clear();
oldMap = newMap;
```

My question: Why does it change anything?  Doesn't a pointer reassignment tell Java that the map and its content are no longer needed and it can clear the data and reuse the space for whatever purpose?

Note: This is running Java HotSpot 1.7.  With Java HotSpot 1.6, I run out of memory much more quickly with the first approach, which isn't clear to me why either.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your code looks like. If you only *ever* initialized `newMap` before the loop, then you'd just get one map which potentially got bigger and bigger. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would be much easier to explain...

Comment: At the end of the call to `map.clear()` , the contents of the map would fall out of scope and be inaccessible and subject to GC. However, during a reassignment, `oldMap` is still scope-accessible (despite there being no references to it) and wouldn't be able to be GC'd until after the end of the `for` loop (I believe). But, given that @JonSkeet is here, I'm just going to go ahead and stand down.

Comment: @ColinMorelli See my comment in the answer for the silly mistake I was making.  However, I am not clear about your "oldMap is still scope-accessible (despite there being no references to it) and wouldn't be able to be GC'd until after the end of the for loop".  Can you expand on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it shouldn't make any difference in terms of memory - you must have another reference to `oldMap` floating around that's preventing it from being GC'd (if object1 and object2 both point to `oldMap`, and you update object1 to point to `newMap`, then object2 will still be pointing to `oldMap` which will prevent it from being GC'd)

Comment: Oh silly me.  I just realized that my CostAndIndex still held pointers to State objects computed in the previous pass.  This is why a reassignment didn't free up the space: there were indeed references to elements inside oldMap preventing the memory freeing.